# How do I upload files to remote servers using scripts

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Batch: I can upload using xcopy but I would like to loop/recurse by using next server name from servers.txt

Powershell: Can't use copy-item because can't use -Credential.  Use start-job and have error scriptblock "specify a parameters of type 'system.management.automation.scriptblock' and try again.```

what I have tried is in the summary and code provided.

PS1:

```
Read-Host "Er Password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-    File c:\temp\PSCred.txt
$Pass = cat PSCred.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$User = Read-Host "ER userID"
$computers = gc "C:\temp\servers.txt"
$source = "C:\temp\UPowercli.exe"
$destination = "C$\temp\"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $sb = [scriptblock]::create("Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$destination -Recurse")
    start-job -scriptblock -Credential $User $Pass $sb
}
```

BAT:

```
C:\temp>net use \\server.domain.com /user:%user% %password%
```

The command completed successfully.

```
C:\temp>xcopy /y "c:\temp\uninstallpowercli.bat"  "\\server.domain.com\c$\temp"
```

Comment: You do know that `net.exe` and `xcopy.exe` are just executable files, so should work equally as well under `powershell.exe` as under `cmd.exe`, don't you?

Comment: yes, but doesn't answer my question or not understanding where you are getting to.

Comment: Open up a `powershell.exe` window and enter the following, `net use /?`. Now open up a `cmd.exe` window and enter `net use /?`. Take a look at them side by side and see if there is any difference. When you realise that there isn't you should understand that your [tag:batch-file] which is being invoked to run `net.exe` is not necessary, because [tag:powershell] can run it directly. The situation is the same with `xcopy.exe`.

Comment: I got it working. I over think the script when it's actually simple. I think it's because by reading too many similar questions  and codes available on Google.